# Is there any recursive definition, using only addition, of the set of values of $x^2+y^2$?

Tags: number-theory, logic, arithmetic, incompleteness

There is a recursive definition of the set of squares which uses only addition:

$CS(x,y) := IS(x) \wedge IS(y) \wedge x \lt y \wedge \forall z: (x
\lt z) \wedge (z \lt y)⇒\neg IS(z)$

$IS(x)⇔ x=0 \vee x=1 \vee \exists y: \exists z: (CS(z,y) \wedge IS(y)
\wedge (\forall z: (y < z \wedge z < x) ⇒ \neg IS(z))
\wedge x + z = y + y + 2)$

($IS$ stands for IsSquare, $CS$ stands for ConsecutiveSquares.)

Expanding $CS$ in terms of $IS$ gives an axiom in the language:

$IS(x) ⇔x=0 \vee x=1 \vee

\exists y: \exists z: 
(IS(z) \wedge IS(y) \wedge z \lt y \wedge \forall w: (z \lt w) \wedge (w \lt y)⇒\neg IS(w)) \wedge 
IS(y) \wedge

(\forall z: (y < z \wedge z < x) ⇒ \neg IS(z)) \wedge

x + z = y + y + 2

$

This seems to generalize to a recursive definition, using only addition, of the set of values of any univariate polynomial.  Formally I am considering Presburger arithmetic with a unary predicate and associated axioms, [yielding an incomplete system in this case](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/35995/1284).

There are [other unary predicates](http://www.math.osu.edu/~friedman.8/pdf/0AppB072710.pdf) which result in a complete theory.  But my question is:

Is there any recursive definition, using only addition, of [the set of values of $x^2+y^2$](http://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/20008.5.shtml)?  If so, does it yield an incomplete system?  Otherwise, how to prove that such a definition does not exist?

I recently asked ["Is there no univariate integer polynomial that takes on the same positive values as the multivariate polynomial $x^2+y^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111866/is-there-no-univariate-integer-polynomial-that-takes-on-the-same-positive-values) and accepted an answer but I don't understand how to apply it to this situation.

Comment: Do you mean $\{z\mid\exists x\exists y:x\cdot x+y\cdot y=z\}$, but first you want to define multiplication recursively?

Comment: @Asaf, no, I want some definition of IsSumOfTwoSquares in terms of itself (and addition), and if _that_ is somehow possible I would like to know whether it can define multiplication (which implies the system is incomplete (or else inconsistent of course)).

Comment: @Dan Brumleve: Your recursive definition of $IS$ uses an auxiliary predicate, so presumably that is allowed. However, how does one rule out the auxiliary predicate $P(x,y,z)$ that says that $z=xy$?

Comment: @Dan Brumleve: The predicate $P$ can be defined recursively in terms of addition, in the usual way.

Comment: @André, in the case of the set of squares, we _can_ define multiplication, in accordance with your answer to my old question that I linked to.  The case I am wondering about here is the set of sums of two squares.

Comment: @André, sorry, I meant to say that the auxiliary predicate $CS$ is defined only in terms of _addition_ and $IS$.  The point is that $IS$ is defined in terms of itself, $CS$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

The function 
$$
f(z) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & (\exists x)(\exists y)[z = x^2 + y^2]\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
is primitive recursive. Therefore there is a recursive definition for this function which uses only the constant $0$ and the successor function $S(z) =z+1$ as starting points.